# Select 2 rows distinct and other columns on same query

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have been trying to extract a specific query but I just can't figure out how I can do that. All my tries I get errors and errors.

I want something simple:

I have a table with columns: A,B,C,D

```
A -> ID
B -> Date 
C -> REGION
D -> VALUE
```

Since its a table created from trigger there is no key and I have many duplicated records.

I need to select distinct columns A and C together and show it in A,B,C,D output.

Comment: What do you mean by _A and C together and show it in A,B,C,D output_? What is your current and expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is not very clear.

Something like this?

```
select id a, fecha b, region c, value d 
  from test_stack t
 where (t.id, t.region) in 
       (select  distinct d.id a
                       , d.region b 
           from test_stack d);
```